# How to parse a .css file generated by Mathematica? modify values, add some values

Tags: html, css

How can I parse a .css file generated by Mathematica, for example when exporting a notebook to HTML? What is te best way to modify or add new values to the CSS?

I've written a simple function to add some values to a .css file:

```
ImportTxt[file_, Elements_: "String"] :=  Module[{file1 = file, absoluteFileName,    fileNameTxt}, (fileNameTxt = ((FileNameDrop[           absoluteFileName = AbsoluteFileName[#]] <> "\\" <>           FileBaseName[#]) &@file) <> ".txt");   If[FileExistsQ[fileNameTxt], DeleteFile[fileNameTxt];    CopyFile[file, fileNameTxt]; Import[fileNameTxt, Elements],    CopyFile[file, fileNameTxt]; Import[fileNameTxt, Elements]]]

ExportCSS[file_, content_] :=  Module[{fileTxt = file <> ".txt", fileCss = file <> ".css"},   Export[fileTxt, content];   If[FileExistsQ[fileCss], DeleteFile[fileCss];    RenameFile[fileTxt, fileCss], RenameFile[fileTxt, fileCss]]]

cssAdd[cssFile_, name_, value_] :=  Module[{cssFileTxt},   If[FileExistsQ[cssFile] == False, Print["File-Not-Exists"];    Abort[]]; cssData = ImportTxt[cssFile, "Data"];   cssDataList =    Partition[SplitBy[cssData, StringMatchQ[#, "/*" ~~ __ ~~ "*/"] &],     2];  pos = Position[cssDataList, "." <> name <> " {"][[1]];  result = Insert[cssDataList, value, pos + {0, 0, 1}];  ExportCSS[cssFile // StringDrop[#, -4] &,    StringJoin@Map[Riffle[#, "\n"] &, result, {1, 2}]]]
```

For example:

```
cssAdd["index", "Text", "width:300px;"]
```

will add the value `width:300px;` to the css file, but I encounter problems if I try to do this manipulation repeatedly.

If I continue, changing the value `width:300px;` into `width:500px;`, the second value doesn't work (ie. `width:300px;` will override the `width:500px;`).

In my code： I use `pos + {0, 0, 1}` to get the position where the new value will be inserted, and I think this could be part of my problem.

Let me try Reverse a sublist:

```
width:500px;

width:300px;
```

In context this looks like:

```
.Text{ 
width:500px;
width:300px;
padding:8px;
}
```

This is how I think it should look:

```
.Text{ 
width:300px;
width:500px;
padding:8px;
}
```

---

How can this approach be improved? For example, is it better to import as "String" or "Data"?

Since `PageWidth` doesn't seem to take effect after exporting to HTML,  I need to manually map the value of `PageWidth` to the `width` in.css file.

---

Update one of my solution: I find the place of "}" after ".Text {"

```
pos1=Position[cssDataList,"."<>name<>" {"][[1]];
level=pos1[[1;;2]];
pos2=Select[Position[cssDataList,"}"][[All,-1]],#>pos1[[-1]]&]//First;
result=Insert[cssDataList,value,Append[level,pos2]];
```

Comment: @cormullion hi, I think you know much about something about .css file.

Comment: 500px will override 300px, yes, but isn't this what you want?

Comment: @Anon no, `300px` override `500px`, my function add a new value just after `.name {`

Comment: Hi - no I know very little about CSS, except that it cascades (inherits). But your question isn't clear - what are the different selectors for `width`. What is overriding what? And your 'parser' won't work on all CSS files (they can be very complex- even containing image data). I wonder why Mathematica doesn't parse CSS files?

Comment: @cormullion ah, fine, I mean the .css file generated by Mathematica Exporting notobook to HTML.

Comment: @cormullion overriding means in the HTML file in Explorer, which value takes effect, when there are two `width:300px; width:500px;`, only the second `width:500px;` takes effect, however each time I add value from the first line.

Answer (score 3):

You've added some additional data since I started working on my solution and I now have a better understanding of your problem. You attempted to replace a value and ended up with

```
.Text{ 
width:500px;
width:300px;
padding:8px;
}
```

It's much easier to append the rule at the end of the file, so you get:

```
.Text{ 
width:500px;
padding:8px;
}

.Text{
width:300px;
}
```

This is valid CSS, where the last rule has precedence over the former. In fact, this property of CSS is very, very commonly used. For example almost every website includes a stylesheet that gets rid of browser inconsistencies. Then usually a sort of framework with handy and common rules, and then a  third stylesheet with site-specific styles. Each stylesheet overrides the former. So what you ought to do is create a stylesheet that overrides the Mathematica styles you don't like and include it after you include the Mathematica stylesheet.

However, I've written a simple example of how you can work with CSS. It should work for the most common purposes. It only has one function so far, which is to add/update a property but you can easily extend it.

Let's start with some basic CSS:

```
css = ".navbar-inverse .navbar-brand,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }

  .navbar-static-top,
  .navbar-fixed-top,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom {
    border-radius: 0;
  }

  .alert {
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), 0 \
1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), 0 \
1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  }

  .alert-success {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dff0d8 0%, \
#c8e5bc 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #dff0d8 0%, #c8e5bc \
100%);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-color: #b2dba1;
    filter: \
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffdff0d8', \
endColorstr='#ffc8e5bc', GradientType=0);
  }";
```

Here's the parser, I hope it's clear what it does from the comments. The regular expressions are very simple, one can think of them as string patterns where .*? is *_*.

```
{selectors, properties} = 
  Transpose@
   StringCases[StringReplace[css, "\n" -> ""](* The . 
    selector does not match newlines *),
    RegularExpression["(.*?){(.*?)}"] -> {"$1", 
          "$2"} (* $1 is the content of the first parenthesis, $2 that of \
the second *)
    ];
selectors = 
  StringTrim /@ 
   StringSplit[selectors, ","]; (* Selectors are divided by comma *)

properties = 
  StringTrim /@ 
     StringCases[#, 
      RegularExpression["(.*?):(.*?);"] -> {"$1", "$2"}] & /@ 
   properties; (* Each property is of the form name: value; *)

rules = Transpose[{selectors, properties}];
```

Now execute `rules // TableForm` and inspect the values. To change a value I created this utility function:

```
propertyUpdate[rules_, selector_, name_, value_] := If[
  MatchQ[rules, {___, {{___, 
      selector, ___}, {___, {name, ___}, ___}}, ___}](* 
  The property already has a value *),
  rules /. {x___, {s : {___, selector, ___}, {a : ___, {name, ___}, 
       b : ___}}, y___} :> {x, {s, {a, {name, value}, b}}, y},
  Append[rules, {selector, {{name, value}}}]
  ]
```

To try it, execute this and compare with the original value:

```
propertyUpdate[rules, ".alert", "box-shadow", "newValue"] // TableForm
```

Comment: ha, thanks, I need time to digest your answer. I see one important thing is we can just add a total `.Text {width:300px;}` in the end of the file, that broaden the functions we could write. I've added a solution along my function, find the place of `"}"`.